# Navigating multiple carousel items with bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make carousel items navigate as a group with bootstrap 3? Rather than moving items one at a time how can we make the multiple items move at a click. For e.g. If i see slides 1,2,3 the next carousel control should display slides 4,5,6.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="images\link4\Picture1.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="images\link4\Picture2.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="images\link4\Picture3.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="images\link4\Picture4.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="images\link4\Picture5.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="images\link4\Picture2.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="images\link4\Picture4.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="images\link4\Picture3.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script>
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next = next.next();
  if (next.length>0) {
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far. It's just matter of putting the slides in a single item: http://www.bootply.com/lFBj86irDS

Comment: Wasted my hours on this to get it work. Couldn't think of this. Truely appreciate your help on this. Thanks very much Zim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the extra JS. Just use the standard Bootstrap carousel...

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/Vnvl4HqgKJ

Comment: how do i accept answer? is there any link? sorry i am new to this forum. Please guide.